google search console not showing 'Page Indexing report' Issue data? How to resolve this?

Hi, Suddenly i want to check of my website issue reports but Search console not showing any data. anyone can help how to resolve this issue because its first time to me and i don't understand this. its showing error's but not showing the website Url's. I mention a image to understand the issue

There should be a list of example URLs right below these charts. The fact that they are not showing could indicate the following problems:

Caching issue in your browser (try to open Google Search Console in an incognito tab, or clearing the cache for the site)
API issues at Google (in this case you just have to wait and retry but you might be able to see failing requests in the network tab of your browsers developer tools)
Permission issue (you can check that your permissions are not restricted under "Settings". If you are a verified owner you should be able to see that data)

In addition you can also try to access a list of redirect URLs via "Settings" -> "Crawl stats".
Hope this helps.

Hi Tobias Schwarz, Thanks for the reply & i take all the steps as per your guidance but still my issue is not resolve. any other Idea do you have how to resolve ?

one more thing if I'm export my report so in the sheet same issue (URL's not mentioned there)

The only additional thing I can think of is to delete the property and than add it again, but you might loose data in the process.
